# Does iOS provide a multiple 'apk' support as Android does?

Tags: android, ios, apk, publishing

I'm creating a multiplayer game with a popular engine which ports the game to Android and iOS.

There are 5 different aspect ratios on these companies devices so I'm creating 5 different packs of UI (graphics) with different sizes.

It would be so stupid to download/store all of the graphics (16:9, 4:3...) on a  for example 5:3 device so I found this: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

I can publish 5 versions of the app depending on the screen resolution and user automagically gets correct.

Does iOS provide a similar thing? I can't find anything saying so.

Thank you very much!

Comment: No you only upload one bundle to iTunes Connect.

Comment: So there is complately no option to do this?

Comment: Just posted an answer with some more information on possible steps you can take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 9 Apple supports App Thinning. You can now use slicing to have certain resources only be downloaded for specific devices. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) is the official documentation on App Thinning. Sounds like for your case you would want Slicing.

Few important things to mention. Depending on the game engine you are using this might not be supported. Also unlike Google Play you are still only uploading one bundle to iTunes connect. Apple takes care of slicing the resources and takes care of App Thinning behind the scenes after you set it up.

**EDIT** of course you could also use on demand resources or something to send the resources at run time. You could also set something like this up on your own if your game engine doesn't support App Thinning. Just download the resources from some server at runtime. There are many different options and it all depends on the game engine you are using and how you want to set it up.

Comment: Thanks for an extended response! I thought about downloading the assets - it's the only option now because my game engine doesn't allow to modify anything deep in the code so I can't use Thinning.

I will leave the answer unticked so someone will maybe point something else! :)

Comment: @Qbix if you're game engine doesn't support Thinning or anything like that your only option is to do something custom. App Thinning is the only thing Apple supports that's built in. And what do you mean by unticked?

Comment: I meant I will not accept your answer for a moment so people would be more interested in this topic! :) But Charlie, Apple allows to download files and store them on device/internal/external storage, right?

Comment: @Qbix Sounds good. Accept it at some point if it helped you haha. Yes Apple allows you to download files and store them on the device. But iOS devices don't have external storage so it would be internal only.

Comment: Thanks for the help!